# How to rotate View Component in react native for android

Tags: android, react-native

I want to rotate the view component in react native. I found the css styling like `transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}]`. This work great for iOS but not for android. In android, the rotation occurred but the pivot was not in the centre as it was for iOS, instead it was at the top right corner. So it was rotating terribly wrong. I want the pivot at the centre of view. Thanks

Comment: Are u using surface view?

Comment: I am using react-native view. import View from 'react-native'

Answer (score 0):

Android only supports the "rotate" key in the transform attribute on React Native when you use 'rad' instead of 'deg' `rotate: ".05rad"`.

To convert degrees to rad...
`degreeValue * Math.PI / 180`. The easier solution is to use `rotateZ`. This allows you to use degrees and works on both platforms.

I was using react-native-reanimated and ran into this problem. Simple change you can make (works on BOTH platforms)

```
const rotatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          rotateZ: `${someValue}deg`,
        },
      ],
    };
});
```